# Difference between Endpoint, Skeleton, and Servant?

Tags: web-services, soap, implementation, endpoint, corba

I would like to know the differences between an **Endpoint**, **Skeleton** and **Servant**.

For me it's the same thing, they are all "**Implementation Classes**", but when I do SOAP I see "*Endpoint*", when I do RMI I see "*Skeleton*", and when I do CORBA I see "*Servant*" words...

Can you explain me the differences / subtleties ?

Thanks

Comment: CORBA, RMI, and SOAP are all different technologies and they may define terms differently, or the terms you mentioned may not appear in them at all. Which technology are you asking about?

Comment: Well I use all of them (SOAP, RMI, CORBA)... I think I am doing a confusion when I say that "Skeleton" is an implementation, because Skeleton is just a server-side generated code. But I am almost sure that "Endpoint" (SOAP) and "Servant" (CORBA) represent the same thing : the implementation class created by the developer.

Comment: in SOAP, endpoint represent ur service address. In any WSDL, under service tag, within <soap:address location> tag, u will find your Endpoint. And using ur wsdl if u can generate the skeleton of ur webservice i.e. getter and setter class along with interface and implementation classes.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to read the [CORBA Explained Simply book](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/). In CORBA all three terms are used.